# How does spaceship gets the #id value for .cer files from Apple Developer Portal?

Tags: ios, x509certificate, fastlane, apple-developer, spaceship-operator

I have the **.cer** certificate that is downloaded from **Apple Developer Portal** of the client I don't have authentication for. I am running **openssl x509** to read the **.cer** which doesn't shows any value that matches the **#id** (the name on the **.cer** and **.p12** that gets uploaded to the fastlane managed repo) but the **Team Id** and **Team Name**

Please suggest how do I get the **#id** value locally when I can't get the certs using **Spaceship** (which does return the **#id** value once I login to Spaceship)?

Reference:

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/fastlane/spaceship/Spaceship/Certificate

Comment: Why do you need the certificate id of a .cer file? Knowing that might help giving a response to your second question.

Comment: I assume https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285747/how-does-spaceship-gets-the-id-value-for-cer-files-from-apple-developer-portal/55286008?noredirect=1#comment97303412_55286008 should have been a reponse here. If you want to manually add things to your `match` repo, you should have a look at https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/other/#manually-manage-the-fastlane-match-repo I am not sure if you actually have to name your files by the certificate ID to be honest.

Comment: Oh so I am able to encrypt and decrypt . I know I don't need the id since match won't work anyways but I was just trying if I can run a match if I give proper Id

Comment: I would assume the ID is just a cosmetic thing, as it is handy when creating private key (via the CSR) and downloading the certificate. But I am not sure here. If you need more information maybe ask at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues

Comment: Does match work for a cert/profile stored in fastlane repo but is not on your apple developer portal ? Since match or spaceship needs a login to apple developer portal to fetch the certs for a match

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but there is a readonly mode where stuff should just be used without any online validation. (Assuming with "fastlane repo" you mean the certificate repo of match) (And again: Github issues would be a good place to ask this, or a separate StackOverflow question)

Comment: Following this question. I need to figure out which ID.cer and ID.p12 to replace with a newly generated provisioning profile and certificate manually editing the signing resources repository that fastlane uses in readonly mode

Answer (score 1):

I can answer one of your two questions:

> How does spaceship gets the #id value for .cer files from Apple Developer Portal?

When spaceship creates a certificate it does so by sending a request to an API:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/75302f9f842fb1d7361dc1e769cdd7398022f4b4/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/certificate.rb#L309-L313

The response from that API call is used to create an object (via the `new` above) that also includes an `id` property:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/75302f9f842fb1d7361dc1e769cdd7398022f4b4/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/certificate.rb#L214-L253

That `id` is then used to define the filename the certificate is written to (unless you define a `filename` manually):
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/f32b007ff45e648b37b6c9c2037ac481f36b7780/cert/lib/cert/runner.rb#L191-L195

Comment: I am trying to use external .cer and name the .cer manually using scripts with the ID. 
 My plan is to use same repo as Fastlane to store my external certs and .mobileprovision from external clients (not belonging to the Apple Portal) . I know match/sigh won't work for external cers not authenticated by portal but in those cases I will explicitly build and sign and release